# Code-complete with plotly.graph_objs class in Spyder IDE (5.2.1) does not work as intended

Tags: python, plotly, spyder, code-completion

The Spyder Code-completion with `plotly.graph_objs` class does not display the right functions.

The function `plotly.graph_objs.Histogram` are with capital letter, but is displayed with lowercase and a 'module' instead of 'function'.

I am not sure if there is an error in the way I have installed stuff, or it it is spyder and/or the plotly library itself.

[image: Screenshot of the code-completion issue]

Version infos:

- Python interpreter version: 3.10.1
- Plotly library version: 5.5.0
- Spyder version: 5.2.1 None
- Python version: 3.7.9 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.12.10
- PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
- Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: `go.histogram` is a module in the `plotly.graph_objs` library. I don't have too much familiarity with the Spyder IDE but it might be the case that it won't autocomplete `go.Histogram`. My `Visual Studio Code IDE` won't autocomplete go.Histogram either, but recognizes the method go.Histogram once typed out, and displays the arguments.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sometimes Spyder is unable to show all completions for certain packages. That's sort of normal in Python and we can't fix it, sorry.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks for answering! i think you should post your comment as an answer since people might not always look in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pasting in one of the comments as answer;
**(Spyder maintainer here) Sometimes Spyder is unable to show all completions for certain packages. That's sort of normal in Python and we can't fix it, sorry. – Carlos Cordoba Jan 19 at 4:45**

I have also tested the same `plotly.graph_objs.Histogram`function with autocomplete in MS Visual Code, and Atom. And, it does not work there either.